# Continuous looping scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm using the https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll plugin in react to enable smooth scrolling. I'm trying to get it to do a Continuous scroll so it will loop round no matter what direction you scroll in by adding and removing items in the state array to change the order.

This works but causes some super flicker.

coulep of demos is

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-resonance-0ybkl

https://codesandbox.io/s/young-wind-ozeeq

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-darkness-6gxj1

Any help would be appreciated

code below

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import LocomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      limit: null,
      items: [
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/640/460",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/560",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/640/760",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/860",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/640/160",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/260",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/360",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/460"
      ]
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const target = document.querySelector("#view");
    const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
      el: target,
      smooth: true,
      smoothMobile: true,
      getDirection: true
    });

    scroll.on("scroll", obj => {
      console.log(obj.scroll.y);
      if (this.state.limit !== null) {
        if (obj.direction === "up") {
          var current = this.state.items;

          var first = current.shift();
          current.push(first);
          this.setState(
            {
              items: current
            },
            () => {
              scroll.update();
            }
          );
        }

        if (obj.direction === "down") {
          current = this.state.items;
          var last = current.pop();
          current.unshift(last);
          this.setState(
            {
              items: current
            },
            () => {
              scroll.update();
            }
          );
        }
      } else {
        var halfway = obj.limit / 2;
        scroll.scrollTo(target, halfway);
        this.setState({
          limit: obj.limit
        });
      }
    });

    scroll.scrollTo(target, 1);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="view">
          <div className="left">
            {this.state.items.map(item => {
              return <img src={item} alt="" />;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Could you place your code in the question itself as well? That will make it far more valuable for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting flickering is because the entire component is re-rendering on the scroll event and your elements don't have a key on them.

```
this.setState(
    {
        items: current
    },
    () => {
        scroll.update();
    }
);
```

In the above code, you set the state on a scroll event which will cause a full re-render of the list. You need to set a `key` on your elements that are in a `map` func.

[Key docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-tereshkova-vpfnf)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import LocomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      limit: null,
      items: [
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/640/460",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/560",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/640/760",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/860",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/640/160",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/260",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/360",
        "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/460"
      ]
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const target = document.querySelector("#view");
    const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
      el: target,
      smooth: true,
      smoothMobile: true,
      getDirection: true
    });

    scroll.on("scroll", ({ limit, direction }) => {
      if (this.state.limit !== null) {
        if (direction === "up") {
          console.log("up");
          var current = this.state.items;
          var last = current.pop();
          current.unshift(last);
          this.setState(
            {
              items: current
            },
            () => {
              scroll.update();
            }
          );
        }

        if (direction === "down") {
          current = this.state.items;
          var first = current.shift();
          current.push(first);
          this.setState(
            {
              items: current
            },
            () => {
              scroll.update();
            }
          );
        }
      } else {
        var halfway = limit / 2;
        scroll.scrollTo(target, halfway);
        this.setState({
          limit
        });
      }
    });

    scroll.scrollTo(target, 1);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="view">
          <div className="left">
            {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
              return <img key={`${item}${idx}`} src={item} alt="" />;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: looks like it still flickers, should i not setstate?

Comment: I am not seeing anymore flickering in the codesandbox I linked. I wonder if there are differences in browser? The scrolling seems to be moving crazy fast which I think is just the scrolling logic.

Comment: i'm in chrome. How would that be smoothed out?